# spring mvc rest service, view request and response xml

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to write a simple application using spring mvc as a restful webservice. How do i view the input xml/text received by the webservice and the output xml/text produced. Is it some settings in the logs?

Comment: uses a rest client, if they are get requests use your trusty browser. You would have to set up the logging yourself.

Comment: I am using jaxb, if the response is an object, how do i see the xml version of the object.

Comment: You'll need a `Filter` which wraps (and buffers) the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` and prints their bodies